# Core Data Nested Relationship Fetch Predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

OK so looked for answers and I'm probably making some assumption that others aren't and thats why the solution is working for them.

**Problem**:
Lets say I have an Entity called `DogOwner`. A dog owner can have multiple `Dogs` and each dog can have multiple `Wearables`. Note that all relationships are optional and one-to-many (inverse many-to-one).

**Aim:**
Search all the dog owners that own a dog that has a `Wearable` type `GpsTracker` and contains id of `898764`.

**My approach:**
Fetching the entity `DogOwner` with the following predicate

```
NSPredicate(format: "(dog.wearable.type == %@) AND (dog.wearable.external_id CONTAINS[cd] %@)", theType, theIdentifier)
```

I get an `unimplemented SQL generation for predicate` error.

**Tried** -> with `ANY` ([Nested core data fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335838/nested-core-data-fetch))
Tried other stuff present on the Internet. Nothing as far I have seen works, I assume that the problem is deeper down given that nested tree structured graph is being successfully queried by others using the dot notation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to use SUBQUERY, if only because you need to test both conditions simultaneously:

```
NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(dog, $d, SUBQUERY($d.wearable, $w, $w.type == %@ AND $w.external_id CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0).@count > 0", theType, theIdentifier)
```

Or "fetch DogOwners having more than 0 dogs having more than 0 wearables matching the criteria".

Comment: This is the strategy I have implemented meanwhile. Whilst this gets the job done I don't think it is very efficient. I was looking for in built optimisations within the Core Data. Thank you for the answer though. Will mark it as the right answer if none other better is given.

Comment: @aajwa Another option is to fetch `Wearable` objects using a simpler predicate, and then to use the inverse relationships to get the corresponding `DogOwner`.  You can use @distinctUnionOfObjects to remove duplicates: eg. `fetchedWearables.valueForKeyPath("@distinctUnionOfObjects.dog.dogOwner")`.  No idea which will prove the more efficient!

Comment: @aajwa"Whilst this gets the job done I don't think it is very efficient" What leads you to believe that?

Comment: @quellish My previous experience with MySQL tells me that, or any other SQL database engine I have used. I guess I shouldn't be assuming.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks, was trying to avoid multiple queries. Marking this answer as correct

Comment: @aajwa core data is an object graph management API, not a database.

Answer (score 0):

While subquery is a feasible way to do this it is exceedingly complicated, and unnecessarily so. Why not simply search for the specific `Wearable` and get the owner via the convenient to-one relationships?

```
// fetch wearable with id x
let owner = wearable.dog.owner
```